# Laravel eloquent query not getting proper result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables name verb_exercises and exam_details
I want to display total exercise present in table with total question present in each exercise for particular verb. If not present any question it should display 0

table structure with data

```
CREATE TABLE `verb_exercises` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `is_deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `verb_exercises`
--

INSERT INTO `verb_exercises` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `is_deleted`, `deleted_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'Exercise 3', '2022-01-08 03:15:28', b'0', NULL, '2022-01-08 08:49:54'),
(2, 'Exercise 4', '2022-01-08 03:21:10', b'0', NULL, '2022-01-08 03:21:10'),
(3, 'Exercise 5', '2022-01-08 03:21:24', b'0', NULL, '2022-01-08 03:21:24');


ALTER TABLE `verb_exercises`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

CREATE TABLE `verb_exam_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `details_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `verb_details_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'this is verb id',
  `excercise_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `option1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `option2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `option3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `option4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `is_deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `verb_exam_details`
--

INSERT INTO `verb_exam_details` (`id`, `details_id`, `verb_details_id`, `excercise_id`, `question`, `option1`, `option2`, `option3`, `option4`, `answer`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `is_deleted`, `deleted_at`) VALUES
(1, 8, 1, 1, '015_1080x1080-min.jpg', 'Virtual', 'Aeroplane', 'Boat', 'Car', 'Aeroplane', '2021-12-25 02:00:56', '2022-01-08 09:02:34', b'0', NULL),
(2, 8, 3, 2, 'snowflakes.jpg', 'Coat', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Coat', '2021-12-25 02:13:17', '2022-01-08 08:51:54', b'0', NULL),
(3, 9, 3, 3, 'snowflakes.jpg', 'Coat', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Coat', '2021-12-25 02:13:17', '2022-01-08 08:51:59', b'0', NULL);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `verb_exam_details`
--
ALTER TABLE `verb_exam_details`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `details_id` (`details_id`);
```

This my laravel query

```
DB::table('verb_exam_details')
                        ->select('verb_exam_details.*', 'verb_exercises.name AS ename', DB::raw('COUNT(verb_exam_details.id) AS num_items') )
                        ->join('verb_exercises', 'verb_exercises.id', '=', 'verb_exam_details.excercise_id')
                        ->where([['verb_exam_details.is_deleted', '=', 0],['verb_exercises.is_deleted', '=', 0],['verb_exam_details.verb_details_id', '=', 3]])
                        ->get()
```

**Expected result**

```
Exercise3   0
Exercise4   0
Exercise5   1
```

**Getting result**

```
Exercise4   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this added more specific $id to join clause

```
 $id = $request->id;
DB::table('verb_exercises')
                        ->select('verb_exercises.*','verb_exercises.name AS ename', 'verb_exam_details.excercise_id', DB::raw('COUNT(verb_exam_details.id) AS num_items'))
                        ->leftJoin('verb_exam_details', function ($join)  use ($id) {
                            $join->on('verb_exercises.id', '=', 'verb_exam_details.excercise_id')
                                ->where('verb_exam_details.verb_details_id', '=', $id);
                        })
                        ->where([['verb_exam_details.is_deleted', '=', 0], ['verb_exercises.is_deleted', '=', 0]])
                        ->groupBy('verb_exercises.id')
                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did a lot of changes to the query:

```php
DB::table('verb_exercises')
    ->select('verb_exercises.name', DB::raw('count(verb_exam_details.id) AS num_items'))
    ->leftJoin('verb_exam_details', function (JoinClause $join) {
        $join->on('verb_exercises.id', '=', 'verb_exam_details.excercise_id')
            ->where('verb_exam_details.is_deleted', '=', 0)
            ->where('verb_exam_details.verb_details_id', '=', 3);
    })
    ->where('verb_exercises.is_deleted', '=', 0)
    ->groupBy('verb_exercises.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: still does not show ** Exercise3   0 **  also verb_exam_details.verb_details_id value will be changed as per need

Comment: ok, just realized it's a bit more tricky, gimme a second

Comment: completely changed the query, please try running it @MohitPatel

Comment: @MohitPatel updated it further, what are the results?

Comment: i have runned but not working

Comment: so what is the error with the latest version?

Comment: @MohitPatel last ping in case you want to solve it. Will be heading off.

Comment: there is no error i want data of exercise aswell which has 0 questions like exercise 3 -0 @
Andrius Rimkus